# Getting Spotify API access token from frontend JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, cors, spotify

I have a web app that allows people to generate a list of songs by artists that are related to a particular artist. I want to be able to connect to the user's Spotify account and create a playlist for them from that list of songs, but I need to get an access token. I have a developer account and client ID and am trying to work through the Authorization Flow, but it's not working for me. Instead, I get this error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/?client_id=d137fe25b31c4f3ba9e29d85f…:3000/callback&scope=user-read-private%20user-read-email&state=34fFs29kd09. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.`

This is a portion of my `scripts.js` file (i'm using the `spotify-web-api-js` node module):

```
$('#spotify').on('click', function() {
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.getJSON("https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/?client_id=d137fe25b31c4f3ba9e29d85f4e47c66&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fcallback&scope=user-read-private%20user-read-email&state=34fFs29kd09", function(json2){
    $.getJSON("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token/?grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + json2.code + "&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fcallback&client_id=d137fe25b31c4f3ba9e29d85f4e47c66&client_secret={...}", function(json3) {
      s.setAccessToken(json3.access_token);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

According to my research, it's a CORS-related issue. I'm making edits to my ExpressJS server to remedy this cross-origin problem and installed the `cors` node module, but I'm still getting the same error.

`index.js` server:

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
var port = 3000;

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});


 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // looks in public directory, not root directory (protects files)

 app.get('/', function(req, res) {
     res.send(__dirname + '\\index.html')
});

app.listen(port, function() {
          console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

When I go to the URL in question directly through my browser, it gives me the expected "Do you authorize this app to use your Spotify information" form.

Should I require 'cors' in 'scripts.js' for it to work? Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue here is that you're attempting to retrieve JSON data  from the endpoint where you should direct your users. So instead of making a request to it, you should supply a button on your page that links to your https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/{...} URL. The user will proceed to give your application the permissions you've requested as specified in the `scope` parameter, and will be directed back to the URL you've specified in the `redirect_uri` parameter. This is where you get the authorization code, which you can use in the https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token/{...} endpoint. Read more about the Authorization Code flow in the [Authorization Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow).

Spotify Web API support three different oAuth flows, and you might be interested in [Implicit Grant](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#implicit-grant-flow). Examples of all of these flows written in Javascript using Node is available at https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples.

Comment: Thank you, this helped with that problem. However, after I authorized the app to use my Spotify information, it redirects to `Cannot GET /callback?code={bunch of random letters and numbers I haven't seen before}`, and none of the oAuth flows or other answers here seem to explain that issue well enough for me. I have `localhost:3000/callback` (3000 is my server port) listed as a redirect in developer settings. I'm attempting to retrieve the access token through `getJSON` in a different function after the user follows the link & `json` is not defined, could that be the problem?

Comment: The value in the `code` parameter is called the authorization code. Your application can send this code by sending a `POST` request to https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token, as described in step 4 at https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow. (It's possible that you're sending a `GET` instead of a `POST`.) Make sure that your local web server is running on port 3000, and also that the redirect URI that you've configured in My Applications at https://developer.spotify.com/  has port 3000 as well.

Comment: I believe it's doing a GET request instead of a POST...how can I make sure this doesn't happen?

Comment: jQuery documentation will help, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ perhaps. This is a separate problem though, so I think it warrants a different Stack Overflow question.

Comment: agreed, so i'm closing this and accepting your answer--it helped with my immediate problem!