# Spotify API access_token no longer appearing

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify, browserify, access-token

I had a working Node.js app using the `spotify-web-api-js` node module and the Spotify API with async, browserify and JavaScript in order to save particular songs to a user's playlist. Unfortunately, I tried to make some changes in order to deploy to heroku and appear to have messed it up. I tried rolling back my git commits and even reverting to the previous working version of the code on my Dropbox account, but it doesn't seem to be working the same.

At this point, I have the array of song URIs that need to go into an array and get sent to the Spotify API according to the node module, but it doesn't seem to be able to get the access token needed for that.

Here is some of the relevant code:

```
function getHashParams() {
  var hashParams = {};
  var e, r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g,
      q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
  while ( e = r.exec(q)) {
     hashParams[e[1]] = decodeURIComponent(e[2]);
  }
  return hashParams;
}

var params = getHashParams();
```

And then a bunch of code that actually does the search and puts the related tracks into an array, still working as usual. After that, comes this part, which involves a user clicking a button and logging into their Spotify account:

```
  if (params.access_token) {

          s.setAccessToken(params.access_token);
          s.getMe().then(function(data) {


            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.id);
            user_id = data.id;

            s.createPlaylist(user_id, {name: 'Related Artist Playlist'}).then(function(data3) {
              console.log(data3);
              playlist_id = data3.uri;
              playlist_id = playlist_id.substring(33);
              console.log(playlist_id);
              console.log(user_id);
              console.log(song_uris);





              s.addTracksToPlaylist(user_id, playlist_id, song_uris).then(function(data){
                  console.log(data);
                });
```

I did a `console.log` on `params.access_token` and it shows up as `undefined`, which explains why the code below the if statement doesn't run. When looking at my server terminal, I see that the account login worked, but the information is no longer being logged to the console, and it's not saving anything to the Spotify account.

Is there anything i'm missing here, as to why it's no longer functioning? There doesn't seem to be any problem with their servers. I had a [somewhat similar issue previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33029349/getting-spotify-api-access-token-with-node-js-express-js) with getting the access token, but this seems to be different because I made the server changes and modified the link on my page as suggested, and i'm not getting any of those CORS errors.

Comment: What is the URL of the page where you are running the code? Is that the page you are redirecting to as part of the OAuth2 flow?

Comment: @JoséM.Pérez I am running the code on `localhost:3000/finalproject`. The login button is linked to `localhost:3000/login`, and once I approve the connection it redirects to the same `finalproject` page as before, except with the extra token parameters in the URL, as in `http://localhost:3000/finalproject/#access_token={BLAHBLAHBLAH}&refresh_token={BLAHBLAHBLAH}`

Comment: If looks like you get the access token in the URL, which means that you should be able to read it using the getHashParams() function, which just parses the hash string and extracts an object with key-value pairs.

Comment: @JoséM.Pérez did I make a typo defining `getHashParams()` then? Or maybe I define the `params` parameter it saves the data into in the wrong place. Code snippet: http://pastebin.com/F4afh9Pb

Comment: @JoséM.Pérez `var params = getHashParams();` is an empty object when I `console.log` it, even when I wrap it all in an event listener so that it would wait for someone to click the button first.